# Using instance methods with chartkick in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chartkick

I have a model, teams that has an instance method point_differential (basically points for - points against). I am trying to use it in a chartkick graph, but with no luck.

This works

> = bar_chart Team.group(:group).sum(points_for)

because points_for is just an attribute of the Team model.

This doesn't because point_differential is an instance method, not an attribute

> = bar_chart Team.group(:name).sum(point_differential)

Neither does

> = bar_chart Team.group(:name).sum(&:point_differential)

Neither does

> bar_chart = Team.all.map {|team| {name:team.name, point_differential:
>   team.point_differential}}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last option there is almost correct, but you have the wrong format.

Consider your first example:

```
Team.group(:group).sum(:points_for)
```

This would create a hash like the following:

```
{"Team A" => 14, "Team B" => 9}
```

In your last example you did this:

```
Team.all.map {|team| {name:team.name, point_differential: team.point_differential}}
```

Which would create *an array* of hashes like the following:

```
[{:name => "Team A", :point_differential => 14}, {:name => "Team B", :point_differential => 9}]
```

Instead, try this:

```
Hash[ *Team.all.map { |team| [team.name, team.point_differential] }.flatten ]
```

This is an esoteric one liner that takes an array of arrays (each 2 elements), and creates a hash out of them, giving you something like this:

```
{"Team A" => 14, "Team B" => 9 }
```

Like you want.

Another way, showing more steps to do this, is like this:

```
hash = {}
Team.all.each do |team|
  hash[team.name] = team.point_differential
end
```

Then that `hash` will have the right values.

Comment: Thanks! That was the exact route I went once I noticed the array of hashes thing. We were posting at the same time. Thanks for the one liner!

Comment: Ha no problem! You should definitely wrap it in a method like you proposed though. But, if I may make a suggestion, don't put that method on one of your models, because it's very specific to a gem you're using. What if you use a different gem later on that wants a different structure? Consider a custom class/method like `ChartHelper.player_point_differentials` or putting it in a helper.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by writing a class method to build a hash using inject

```
def self.hashify_points_differential
   Player.all.inject({}) do |result, player|
     result[player.name] = player.point_differential
     result
    end   
end
```

Then I can just use it like

```
= bar_chart Player.hashify_points_differential
```